# Appending a List--Segmentation fault

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am trying to append  one list with another . If i  pass a pointer-to-the-pointer  of both the lists and just display them, then , the code works fine. But if i use code to reach the NULL pointer of the first list and then equate it to the first one of the second, then it gives a segmentation fault. Please let me know what the mistake is. Code is  below :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node 
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
}*Head,*New;
void display(struct node **p)
{
    struct node *curptr;
    curptr=*p;
    if(curptr==NULL)
        printf("list is empty");
    else
    {
        while(curptr)
        {
            printf("->%d",curptr->data);
            curptr=curptr->next;
        }
    }
}
void combine(struct node **a,struct node **b)
{
    //display(&(*a));
    struct node *aptr;
    aptr=*a;
    while(aptr)
        aptr=aptr->next;
    aptr->next=*b;
    *b=NULL;
    display(&(*a));

    //display(&(*a));
    //display(&(*b));   

}
void main()
{
    Head=NULL;
    New=NULL;
    int choice;
    while(1)
    {
          case 9:
        {
            printf("Combining two lists");
            combine(&Head,&New);
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
while(aptr)
    aptr=aptr->next;
aptr->next=*b
```

When you break out of the `while` loop `aptr` will be `NULL` next when you try to do `aptr->next` you get the SEGV.

To fix this break out of the loop when you reach the last node(`aptr->next` will be `NULL`) rather than `aptr` becoming `NULL`.

Something on these line:

```
// if fist list does not exist.
if(*a == NULL) {
        *a = *b;
        return;
}

struct node *aptr;
aptr=*a;

// loop till you reach the last node of fist list.
while(aptr->next)
        aptr=aptr->next;

// append.
aptr->next=*b;
*b=NULL;
```

Comment: Oh yeah, i made it  while(aptr->next->next) and now its working. Thanks a lot. embarassing mistake :( :( :(

Comment: `aptr->next->next` will cause a segfault too if you have a list of one element.

Comment: @crazy, how do you create new nodes ? I guess you do `malloc(sizeof(struct node));` ? After you do that, do you set `next = null` to avoid having dangling-garbage pointers?

Comment: @Buyukliev, oh  i did not think of that, Thanks.  @Coaddict, yes problem solved. Thanks .  @Muggen,  yes i create new nodes the way you  say it .  I set next==NULL only if its the first element  otherwise not.

Comment: @crazy, you should, because in case you add the new node to the end, that way the last item will point somewhere, and trying to use that will result in Undefined Behaviour (simply speaking, SegFault)

Comment: Oh hmmmmm.  i gotta address that issue then.

Answer (score 2):

```
while(aptr)
  aptr=aptr->next;
```

runs till aptr is NULL, after that

```
aptr->next=*b;
```

causes a segmentation fault since you dereference NULL.